# Selenium is not identifying CKEditor window pop up from textEditor toolbar

Tags: selenium, ckeditor

WebDriver is not able to identify the aricle link window that pops when when clicked on the toolbar button of CKEditor. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not really a programming issue.

Comment: It will definitely be inside an iFrame. Swith to iFrame if one exists.